# How to select only few columns from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one json file about ansible inventory where I need to select few columns as dataframe and send email notification.

The following is code I tried:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
with open('d:/facts.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
mydata = json_normalize(d['ansible_facts'])
mydata.head(1)`
```

Its printing entire records (actually each json will have only one record), but I need to show/select/display only two columns from dataframe. can some one suggest please how to view dataframe with selected columns

**Update 1:**
I am able to generate required columns now,but only certain column working, but when i mention certain columns, then its saying "not in index"
And also can i have own column custom header lable while printing ?
**Working**

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
with open('d:/facts.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
mydata = json_normalize(d['ansible_facts'])
mydata.columns = mydata.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.strip())
df1=mydata[['ansible_architecture','ansible_distribution']]
```

But when i mention column as hostname,ansible_distribution, its saying not in index.
**Not working**

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
with open('d:/facts.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
mydata = json_normalize(d['ansible_facts'])
mydata.columns = mydata.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.strip())
df1=mydata[['hostname','ansible_distribution']]
```

Error:
KeyError: "['hostname'] not in index"

Update2:

Now i am able to fix that issue with below, but I need custom label in output, how to do that

```
`import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
with open('d:/facts.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
mydata = json_normalize(d['ansible_facts'])
mydata.columns = mydata.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.strip())
df1=mydata[['ansible_env.HOSTNAME','ansible_distribution']]`
```

But i need to have custom columname lable in final output like Host,OSversion for above column, how can i do that?

**UPDATE 3**: now trying to rename columns name before I print it, tried following code but giving error like key error not in index

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
with open('/home/cloud-user/facts.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
mydata = json_normalize(d['ansible_facts'])
mydata.columns = mydata.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.strip())

mydata=mydata.rename(columns={"ansible_env.HOSTNAME": "HOSTNAME", "ansible_disrribution": "OSType"})
df1=mydata[['HOSTNAME','OSType']]
print(tabulate(df1, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ab7.py", line 21, in <module>
    df1=mydata[['HOSTNAME','OSType']]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2682, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2726, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1327, in _convert_to_indexer
    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
KeyError: "['HOSTNAME' 'OSType'] not in index"
```

But if i dont rename, it working perfectly, But i need most readable column lable. any suggestion please.
without rename stuff code get works and output as below on console

```
+----+------------------------+------------------------+
|    | ansible_env.HOSTNAME   | ansible_distribution   |
|----+------------------------+------------------------|
|  0 | ip-xx-xx-xx-xx         | SLES                   |
+----+------------------------+------------------------+
```

Now instead anisble_env.HOSTNAME --> i need lable as HOSTNAME , instead of ansible_distribution --> I need OSType any suggestion please

Update 4:

I fixed issue with below

```
df.rename(columns={'ansible_hostname':'HOSTNAME','ansible_distribution':'OS Version','ansible_ip_addresses':'Private IP','ansible_windows_domain':'FQDN'},inplace=True)
```

Comment: `mydata[[col1,col2]]`

Comment: A very comprehensive collection of the basic tasks and operations in pandas can be found [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/doc/cheatsheet/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf)

Comment: i tried `mydata[[hostname,ansible_distribution]]` but its saying hostname not in index error

Comment: I have updated original post with additional code that tried, now, certain columns working fine, but  some columns saying 'not in index' error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select multiple columns as a DataFrame by passing a list to it:

```
df[['col_name1', 'col_name2']]
```

For more information try this link: 
https://medium.com/dunder-data/selecting-subsets-of-data-in-pandas-6fcd0170be9c

Comment: Tried this but not working, Its giving KeyError: "['HOSTNAME'] not in index" i.e its saying column not in index

Comment: I have updated original post with additional code that tried, now, certain columns working fine, but  some columns saying 'not in index' error